# Dar formato de separador de miles a un campo creado con trace_add en Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, formato

Debo ingresar un valor (abono). Estoy usando ese valor para que, en la medida que se digita, vaya recalculando un saldo. Para ello uso trace_add y funciona bién.

Lo que quiero es que ese valor que ingreso (abono) se formatee de tal manera que separe las unidades de miles.

Muestro el código que calcula y una pantalla del programa.

def rastreador(var, index, mode):

```
try:
  salAnt = sal[3]
except:
  salAnt = 0
 
try:
  abon = abono.get()
except:
  abon = 0

saldo=salAnt-abon

ventanita=LabelFrame(root)
ventanita.pack()
ventanita.place(x=1025, y=340, width=98, height=25)
Label(ventanita, text='{:,}'.format(saldo), width=11).place(x=0, y=0)
```

abono.trace_add("write", rastreador)

[image: Pantallazo de la captura]

Comment: En que momento el campo abono debe tener los miles separados? Cuando pierde el foco? Cuando el usuario esta escribiendo?

Comment: La idea es que mientras el usuario escribe, vaya poniendo los separadores. Esto con el fin de que sea más claro el valor que introduce.